# Asymptotics Accounting for Invocation Frequency in the Context of the broader system

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotics, runtime-analysis

I did some thinking and analysis this evening and I'm wondering if what I'm pointing out here is interesting:

https://medium.com/@nwcodex/invocation-asymptotics-runtime-cost-based-on-the-anticipated-invocations-of-code-paths-in-the-ed3e0d401970

Could it be that asymptotics are typically only interesting in the context of the frequency of invocation modelled against the probable number of invocations based on the natural world problem space the system containing the relevant code path is deployed to?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.